# In Bootstrap, why can't I customize my cursor to an html element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, cursor

I have a JS fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/b4xrptwL/

When I move my mouse over the button, I get an arrow because of this CSS:

```
#btnL:hover {
    cursor: initial;
}
```

I've tried the same CSS in my table heading,

```
#tableHeading:hover {
    cursor: initial;
}
```

but there I get a text cursor instead of an arrow.

How do I get an arrow when I hover over my table heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below if you need the arrow there as well.

```
#tableHeading:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```